# Is there a way to Detect Unread Text Messages on WP7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms, windows-phone-7.1

I'm looking to build a method which needs to see if there are any text messages on the device which have not currently been read

Is there a way to expose the phones messages to detect whether there are any unread ones and return a bool/int value?

I know in WinMo, you could use SystemState.MessagingSmsUnread to return an int, but I can't seem to find a wp7 equiv.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In Windows Phone there is no way to access the details of any received messages.
This was a deliberate design decision to prevent applications accessing a users personal data without their knowledge.

Comment: Cheers Matt, I thought it might be intentional, but wasn't sure.